# Trying to visualize dom tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there some (preferably Jquery) way of visualizing the dom tree of website like the console log does? I have Googled for an online service, plugin and so one but couldn't find anything. What can I do to make this possible? I know I can just show the html source but Im looking for something more user friendly, like a file tree. For instance if you look at this picture from some editor http://www.kompozer.net/photos/image1.png You will see on the left the kind of file system Im looking for.

Comment: What is your purpose with it? Are the users going to use it? Why not using Chrome inspector or Firefox firebug extension?

Comment: @Steve Sorry for the delay in feedback (I was occupied) I'm working on something "top secret" sow I cant really say much about it. But I would like to give my users the ability to see the dom tree as most of them are going to be "total newbies" or have no programming skills whatsoever